# Why would a react-native view not update after render has successfully run?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a component DeckListView which I navigate to after updating state with redux. When I use the debugger in chrome I can see the this.props.Decks.map((deck) loop going through successfully with a list of data, but when I see the screen I don't see the additional Text. Any idea what may be happening?

I have what I believe to be the key code snippets below. The rest can be found at https://github.com/wcwcaseman/mobile-flashcards

Reducer

```
case ADD_DECK :
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.deck.title]:action.deck,
  }
```

Navigation

```
homePage = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DeckListView');
}
```

Actual page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class DeckListView extends Component {

render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Toast the world</Text>
    {this.props.Decks.map((deck) => {        
            <Text key={deck} >item</Text>
        })}
    </View> 
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps ({ decks }) {

let Decks = [];

if(decks !== {} && decks !== null)
{  
    Decks = Object.keys(decks);
}

return {
    Decks: Decks
}
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DeckListView)
```

Comment: If you use body block (`{}`) in an arrow function you need a `return` statement. Either use it as in the provided answer or drop curlies. In this way, you can implicitly return the value.

Comment: @devserkan Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. You can use the curlies if you do an additional operation before returning your desired value of course. Both methods have their own place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from the map function

```
{this.props.Decks.map((deck) => {        
            return <Text key={deck} >item</Text>
        })}
```

Comment: Hi this worked perfectly thanks so much. I was taught to write like this         {this.props.Decks.map((deck) =>         
                <Text key={deck} >item</Text>
            )} and I did not notice I messed up the brackets. Thank you so much.